# cx-freeze module could not be found, tutorial anyone?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

How do I modify my *setup.py* so that *cx-freeze* finds the modules that is missing? Here is my setup.py:

```
# Usage: Each project must have its own folder. 
# python setup.py build -> build on project directory 
# python setup.py bdist_msi -> bdist_msi to distribute 
# python setup.py install -> on "C:\Program Files" > "access denied" by Windows
# Using: 
# Python          3.7 
# cffi            1.13.2 
# cryptography    2.8    
# cx-Freeze       6.0    
# cycler          0.10.0 
# kiwisolver      1.1.0  
# matplotlib      3.1.2  
# numpy           1.17.4 
# pip             19.3.1 
# pycparser       2.19   
# pyparsing       2.4.5  
# PyQt5           5.13.2 
# PyQt5-sip       12.7.0 
# python-dateutil 2.8.1  
# scipy           1.3.3  
# setuptools      41.2.0 
# six             1.13.0 

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [], include_files = [], includes = [])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('FatigueCalculator.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='', # do not use \, :, etc. 
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'App. for college course Intermediate Mechanics',
    author="Echeban",
    author_email="",
    url="http//mecanica.cadec-online.com",# you can download the .msi
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables)
```

As in many posts I read (but are too hard for me to understand) I can generate a .msi intaller, use it to install the App on another machine, where it will work if Python and PyQt5 are installed but not on yet another machine where those are not installed. The error I get is **line 3 module could not be found**.  Here is the *import* section of my App, so you can see what line 3 is:

```
import sys
import numpy as np 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDoubleValidator
from FatigueDialog import Ui_Dialog # in QtDesigner, using "Dialog"
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QListWidgetItem, QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox
from FatigueKernel import *
from FatigueInteractionCriteria import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
```

The problem seems to be *PyQt5.QtGui*. Next, I moved the offending line almost to the bottom of the list

```
import sys
import numpy as np 
from FatigueDialog import Ui_Dialog # in QtDesigner, using "Dialog"
from FatigueKernel import *
from FatigueInteractionCriteria import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QListWidgetItem, QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox
```

and now fails in line 10 of FatigueDialog.py, which comes from line 3 of the main App. Here is line 10:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

So, I understand cx-freeze fails to grab PyQt5. At the first instance of PyQt5, it fails. 
But how do I modify my setup.py to make it work?

*ADDENDUM*

To simplify my request for help, I downloaded sample code provided by cx-developer Anthony Tuininga. This is a very simple app PyQt5app.py, and setup.py to go with it,

[sample code](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/tree/master/cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt5)

I run `(venv375-32) python setup.py bdist_msi` 
in my development machine, with Windows 10, Python 3.7.5-32 bit, PyQt5           5.13.2, PyQt5-sip 12.7.0.  Then cx-freeze 6.0 with

```
python setup.py bdist_msi > PyQt5app_setup_log.txt
```

The build runs well on the dev. machine. 
I copy the .msi to a machine that does not have PyQt5 installed. I install the .msi, and when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
File PyQt5app.py Line 5 in <module> import error DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Line 5 in the app is:
`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget`

It seems that installation of the PyQt5 DLL fails on the target machine but there is no error during installation, only when attempting to run the app.

*ADDED* a link to publish the output of

```
python setup.py bdist_msi > PyQt5app_setup_log.txt
```

I use cx-freeze 6.0. 
For PyQt5app, I get a msi of 46208 KB. 
Is that large enough to hold Python 3.7 and PyQt?

[PyQt5app_setup_log.txt](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/files/4026149/PyQt5app_setup_log.txt)

Comment: What happens if you use `buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [], include_files = [], includes = ['PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtGui', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'])`?

Comment: @musicamante No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'. Maybe provide the path? but how?

Comment: is that error given while building the binary with cx_Freeze or while trying to run the built executable?

Comment: No error while building the binary with cx-freeze. The .exe found in the build directory runs fine in the dev machine. Installing the msi in the dev machine also works fine. The error occurs when running the app installed via msi on the target machine that does not have python nor PyQt5 installed.

Comment: Please see ADDENDUM, complete minimal example from reputable source, same problem happening, easy to install on your machine.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot test it right now, and I've always created my own packages using InnoSetup as I needed more control over the setup process. That said, the fact that the exe runs fine does not mean that the PyQt libraries are included in the build directory (or even installed). Anyway, what is the size of the .msi file? What version of cx_Freeze do you use? Can you add the output of the bdist_msi command to your question?

Comment: ADDED a link to publish the output of python setup.py bdist_msi > PyQt5app_setup_log.txt

Comment: It seems that the required files are copied indeed. Just to be sure, have you tried to completely remove the build dir and restart the build+bdist_msi again? It's been a while since I've been digging into cx_Freeze, and after that I created custom automation scripts to workaround the issues I had, but I remember I stumbled upon some issues about files that were already present in the build directory from previous (and unsuccessful) builds. By the way, version 6.1 of cx_Freeze has been released a couple of days ago, and it seems it addressed some similar issues. You could try that also.

Answer (score 0):

I was using cx-freeze 6.0. Installed `cx-freeze 6.1` (just released). Froze my app again. Installed it on the target machine. Problem Solved!

PS: the target machine has Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86)-14.0.24123 already installed; it is a requirement; a newer version like 2017 also works; otherwise you get another error.